# Find the number of integer non-negative solutions to $3 x_1+5 x_2+x_3+x_4=10.$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, integer-partitions

> Find the number of integer non-negative solutions to
> $$3 x_1+5 x_2+x_3+x_4=10.$$

**My proposed solution:** First find the possible values for the pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ which are allowed: $(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,0)$, and count solutions for $x_3, x_4$ in each case. Counting for each case is, respectively: 11,6,1,8,3,5,2. They add to a total of 36 solutions.

**My problems:** Given solution in a book is 30 and I would like to know whether my solution is indeed wrong. Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem and similar problems? I believe my approach is kind of brute force.

Comment: Another way to do counts like this is via generating functions. In the present case, you'd look for the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the Taylor series expansion of $$\frac{1}{1-x^3}\frac{1}{1-x^5}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$ If you plug that into WolframAlpha, you get...36, which is what you had ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B1%2F%281-x%5E3%29*1%2F%281-x%5E5%29*1%2F%281-x%29%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C10%7D%5D)). So it's not clear to me that your solution is actually wrong.

Comment: @semiclassical: it is so neat that is arguably wrong :)

Answer (score 6):

your result is true the number of solutions are $36$ for sure.
all solutions are listed here:

$ 1 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=0, x_4=10$

$ 2 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=1, x_4=9$

$ 3 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=2, x_4=8$

$ 4 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=3, x_4=7$

$ 5 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=4, x_4=6$

$ 6 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=5, x_4=5$

$ 7 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=6, x_4=4$

$ 8 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=7, x_4=3$

$ 9 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=8, x_4=2$

$ 10 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=9, x_4=1$

$ 11 :    x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=10, x_4=0$

$ 12 :    x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=0, x_4=5$

$ 13 :    x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=1, x_4=4$

$ 14 :    x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=2, x_4=3$

$ 15 :    x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=3, x_4=2$

$ 16 :    x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=4, x_4=1$

$ 17 :    x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=5, x_4=0$

$ 18 :    x_1=0, x_2=2, x_3=0, x_4=0$

$ 19 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=0, x_4=7$

$ 20 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=1, x_4=6$

$ 21 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=2, x_4=5$

$ 22 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=3, x_4=4$

$ 23 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=4, x_4=3$

$ 24 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=5, x_4=2$

$ 25 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=6, x_4=1$

$ 26 :    x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=7, x_4=0$

$ 27 :    x_1=1, x_2=1, x_3=0, x_4=2$

$ 28 :    x_1=1, x_2=1, x_3=1, x_4=1$

$ 29 :    x_1=1, x_2=1, x_3=2, x_4=0$

$ 30 :    x_1=2, x_2=0, x_3=0, x_4=4$

$ 31 :    x_1=2, x_2=0, x_3=1, x_4=3$

$ 32 :    x_1=2, x_2=0, x_3=2, x_4=2$

$ 33 :    x_1=2, x_2=0, x_3=3, x_4=1$

$ 34 :    x_1=2, x_2=0, x_3=4, x_4=0$

$ 35 :    x_1=3, x_2=0, x_3=0, x_4=1$

$ 36 :    x_1=3, x_2=0, x_3=1, x_4=0$